# jquery: Using :contains with anchor tag

Tags: jquery, anchor, addclass

I want to identify anchor tags  that have an href containing a particular string and then add a class. 
I thought the way to do this might be to use the :contains(text) filter but that appears not to work. I notice in the examples given in the jQuery documentation that the selector is only used to add css to the target element. 
Can you not use this selector to add a class to something like an anchor tag?
My example case follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a:contains("apple")').addclass("monkey");
</script>
```

Where the href in the anchor is http://www.apple.com

This code doesn't work.

Alternatively what is the best way to accomplish my goal of finding anchors that contain particular strings and then adding a class or id to the anchor.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `.addClass` instead of `.addclass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `$('a[href*="apple"]')` instead. `:contains()` checks the inner text of the element.